# Vite how to use sass

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2

[image]

**Vue.config.js**

[image]

when i  install sass and sass-loader  how can i  to configure to use sass
Now i use sass tips error **Cannot find module 'sass' from 'D:\demo\vite'**
[image]

Comment: Please provide the code snippets as code not images...

Answer (score 66):

You just need to install sass using the following command

```
npm install -D sass
```

Also, you may check the official docs here
https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-modules

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
yarn add -D sass
```

it's pretty much the error given in the last screen.

---

Since people prefer to use NPM apparently but that there is a lot of package managers nowadays, here we do have an universal solution

By [using ni](https://github.com/antfu/ni#ni---install), you can have

```
ni -D sass
```

to install that in your project whatever it's using NPM, yarn, PNPM or bun.

Comment: thanks when i create a new project  and i install sass  is ok  But   the old project  can't    I think may be i can't handle good

Comment: Why couldn't the old one handle Sass? Got an error?

Answer (score 3):

btw if you aready did `npm i sass` you can perfectly do `npm i -D sass` the changes will be made automagically!

Answer (score 3):

In other answers, they're using `yarn` or `npm` but If you're using `pnpm`:

```bash
pnpm i -D sass
```

`i` is an alias for `install`:

https://pnpm.io/cli/install

`-d` flag:

https://pnpm.io/cli/install#--dev--d

Answer (score 2):

```
 npm add -D sass
```

Then you can use in your `.vue` file. `<style lang="scss"></style>`

You can find it in vite official website.[Vite scss](https://cn.vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css)