# Nuxt 3 with sass

Tags: css, sass, nuxtjs3

How can we use NUXT3 with sass, also please share the documentation.

I tried to add sass into nuxt3 project, but the vite looks like no options to load scss

Comment: What have you tried so far? This should be enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65589413/8816585 Nuxt should be able to catch the `.sass` itself afterwards.

Comment: Solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547375/global-sass-import-usage-nuxt-3-static-assets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Install it first and save as devDependency

```
$ yarn add sass
# or
$ npm install sass --save-dev
```

### Configure if you want to use global scss

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // more  
  css: [
    // SCSS file in the project
    "~/assets/style/main.scss", // you should add main.scss somewhere in your app
  ],
})
```

### In your components

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
 //...
<style/>
```

Comment: These days you don't need sass-loader anymore

Comment: @jogarcia Are you sure ?  The docs mention it: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/styling#using-preprocessors

Comment: @Tim Read the docs carefully. You have to install sass but not sass-loader

Comment: You are right 

Answer (score 1):

As in a normal vue or vite project you need to install as below

```
// .scss and .sass
npm add -D sass

// .less
npm add -D less

// .styl and .stylus
npm add -D stylus
```

But you need to define the css or scss files in nuxt.config.ts,
As in the example below

```
css: [
  // CSS file in the project
  '@/assets/css/main.css',
  // SCSS file in the project
  '@/assets/css/main.scss'
]
```

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#css