# How to use SCSS in a Hilla (Vaadin) Project

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, hilla

I created a new Hilla React / Springboot project and want to build a custom theme using SCSS. I would like to perform modifications to the out-of-box Lumo theme as well as integrating *Bootstrap* styles and components by including the *Bootstrap* scss. Unfortunately, I cannot find any recent information about how to use sass in Hilla (only a little but incomplete information relating to Vaadin 7). I'd appreciate some hints on

- where to I place the custom style sass files (frontend/themes/<mytheme>/??) -- answered -> see below
- how do I configure the sass parser/css generator? It looks like css files are automatically generated, but they are placed underneath the sass file and thus are not automatically recognized by Hilla -> answered: no configuration required, once sass is a development dependencies (in packages.json)
- how can I make use of the *Bootstrap* css files? I added a Bootstrap dependency to package.json but I am uncertain whether this is the correct approach.

Update: I now figured out how to use sass in the Hilla project (once you know its easy ;-) ):
name the sass file e.g. themes/my-theme/my-styles.scss, then add the following line to `styles.css`:

```
@import "my-styles.scss";
```

Comment: Check this first https://stackoverflow.com/a/66515810/8962195

Comment: This is unfortunately not answering the question, how to use sass specifically in Hilla. I understand how to use sass in a standalone project, but not in conjunction with Hilla/Lumo/custom themes

Comment: Hilla uses Vite for frontend builds, so that way it is directly linked. I.e. you need to have Vite plugin for SASS. Note Bootstrap css does not work with Vaadin components though, as the styles do not propagate to their Shadow DOM. You can use Bootstrap only with native HTML elements.

Comment: It is okay and expected, even desired, that Vaadin components will not be styled by Bootstrap styles. But I'd like to keep custom React components somewhat independent from Vaadin components and themes/styles. This may not seem to make immediate sense, but makes react components reusable in other non-Vaadin/Hilla projects

Answer (score 2):

Hilla uses Vite for frontend builds, so that way it is directly linked. I.e. you need to have Vite plugin for SASS. Note Bootstrap css does not work with Vaadin components though, as the styles do not propagate to their Shadow DOM. You can use Bootstrap only with native HTML elements. There seems to be SO Q&A about setting up SASS Vite plugin here stackoverflow.com/a/66515810/8962195

Comment: I just needed to add sass as a development dependency (as the article from your initial comment suggested) plus the setup, which I described in the updated question. That worked then seamlessly. The only remaining question is how to "best" include the Bootstrap files (copying the sass will obviously work, but feels a bit clunky

Comment: It is in npmjs https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap